# NLP - Speed of Named Entity Recognition (StanfordNER)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm doing Natural Language Processing (NLP) in Python 3 and more specifically Named Entity Recognition (NER) on the Harry Potter set of books. I'm using StanfordNER, which works pretty well but takes incredible amounts of time...

I have done some research online on why it would be this slow but I can't seem to find anything that truly suits my code, and I honestly think the problem lays more in the (bad) way I have written the code.

So here's what I wrote for now :

```
import string
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
import nltk.tag.stanford as st

tagger = st.StanfordNERTagger('_path_/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', '_path_/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/stanford-ner.jar')

#this is just to read the file

hp = open("books/hp1.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8')
lhp = hp.readlines()

#a small function I wrote to divide the book in sentences

def get_sentences(lbook):
    sentences = []
    for k in lbook:
        j = sent_tokenize(k)
        for i in j:
            if bool(i):
                sentences.append(i)
    return sentences

#a function to divide a sentence into words

def get_words(sentence):
    words = word_tokenize(sentence)
    return words

sentences = get_sentences(lhp)

#and now the code I wrote to get all the words labeled as PERSON by the StanfordNER tagger

characters = []
    for i in sentence:
    characters = [tag[0] for tag in tagger.tag(get_words(sentences[i])) if tag[1]=="PERSON"]
    print(characters)
```

Now the problem, as I explained, is that the code takes huge amounts of time... So I'm wondering, is it normal or **can I save time by rewriting the code in a better way ?** If so, could you help me out ?

Comment: How much time is it taking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottleneck is the `tagger.tag` method, it has a big overhead. Therefore, calling it for every sentence results in a really slow program. Unless there's an additional need for splitting the book into sentences, I'd process the whole text at once:

```
with open('books/hp1.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    all_text = content_file.read()
    tags = tagger.tag(word_tokenize(all_text))
    characters = [tag[0] for tag in tags if tag[1] == "PERSON"]
    print(characters)
```

Now if what you wanted to know is, say, what sentence each character is mentioned in, then you could first get the characters' names in `characters` like in the code above, and then loop through the sentences checking if an element from `characters` exists there.

If file size is a concern (although a .txt file of most books shouldn't be a problem to load into memory), then instead of reading the whole book, you could read a number `n` of sentences at once. From your code, modify your for loop like so:

```
n = 1000
for i in range(0, len(sentences), n):
    scs = '. '.join(sentences[i:i + n])
    characters = [tag[0] for tag in tagger.tag(get_words(scs)) if tag[1]=="PERSON"]
```

The general idea is to minimize the calls to `tagger.tag` for its big overhead.